# How can I know when an accelerometer is still? I'm using an external accelerometer via Bluetooth in Swift

Tags: swift, accelerometer

So, I'm connected via Bluetooth to an accelerometer. This device every second is updating values in an array [x,y,z].

Example: [-0.21, 0.01, 0.96]   [-0.22, 0.01, 0.96]   [-0.22, 0.01, 0.96]    [-0.2, 0.02, 0.97]

What I need to do is, from the values I'm getting, check that the accelerometer is not moving. To do so, I have to check that X and Y do not change more than 0.50 and less than 0.50 in a 5 seconds span.

How can I achieve that in Swift? I try different things but I'm not getting results.
This is what I got, but is not going anywhere.

```
if z >= 0.8 && x >= x - 0.5 || x <= x + 0.5 && y >= y - 0.5 || y <= y + 0.5 {
   
   print("User is still")
}
```

The other approach I tried is comparing each array with the previous one, but also, it didn't work.

Comment: Keep results in (circular) buffer and compare.

Comment: @matt could you explain more how you would do it? Thanks

Comment: Well the details depend on what you mean by "0,50 in a 5 second span". But basically you do on the computer just what you would do with your eyes and your brain. I take it that the example you gave is an example that passes the test. Think about how you know that. Then instruct the computer to do what you just did.